# Hi! can anyone tell me how to validate the sha2+salt password while log in?

Tags: hash

can anyone tell me how to validate the sha2+salt password while log in?? i am working in wicket framework and pg admin database, i was told to use hashing algorithm to create secure passwords. I just saw this example source code and i implemented it in my applciation and it just worked, but i dont know how to validate the salt+hash passwords while log in again. But i could able to validate the simple sha-2 paswwords but i couldn't and i don't know how to validate the sha2+salt password.

```
public class SHAExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String passwordToHash = "password";
    String salt = getSalt();

    String securePassword = get_SHA_1_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
    System.out.println(securePassword);

    securePassword = get_SHA_256_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
    System.out.println(securePassword);

    securePassword = get_SHA_384_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
    System.out.println(securePassword);

    securePassword = get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
    System.out.println(securePassword);
}

private static String get_SHA_1_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, String salt)
{
    String generatedPassword = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(salt.getBytes());
        byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        generatedPassword = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return generatedPassword;
}


//Add salt
private static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    sr.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt.toString();
}
```

}

```
 Output:

 e4c53afeaa7a08b1f27022abd443688c37981bc4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the same steps as you did when storing the password hash. That means you calculate the hash of the entered password with the same algorithm and the same salt you used before, then you can compare the hashes.

Be aware that the SHA* hash algorithms are not secure to hash passwords, because they are ways too fast and can be brute-forced too easily. Instead you switch to a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Thank you @martin. BCrypt and SCrypt requires Jars it seems can you suggest a site where i can get jars for this??

Comment: @user3641156 - Unfortunately i'm not familiar with Java, but it seems that [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) is an often recommended implementation.

Comment: @user3641156 - To validate an entered password you should use the function `isCorrect = BCrypt.checkpw(enteredPassword, hashFromDatabase)`. This function will extract the salt and the cost factor from `hashFromDatabase` and can then build a hash with the same parameters.

Comment: this is how i used Bcrypt to save my password into DB but i donno how to validate this while log in, can anyone share me the sample code to validate this??? I have to retrieve password from DB and then i have to validate.. 

    public  String hashPassword(String password) {
    String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(12);
    String hashed_password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);
    return(hashed_password);
    }

Comment: @user3641156 - See my previous comment.

Comment: [$2a$12$xay0LpcAKiLNLf.zocfJZeUZ6aDKr6TkaJ1rvkTfMS.lEsk5aJNQi] 

This is the password i saved into the database in the password column.And then i am retrieving password that belongs to the particular username using a select query--> saved the result in to the list --> conveted it into string --> used that string in the hashFromDatabase and compared it with entered password. I am getting this error now java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt version
    isCorrect = BCrypt.checkpw(enteredPassword, hashFromDatabase)

Comment: @user3641156 - This hash looks quite well. The most common problem is, that the database field for storing the hash value is too short, it must be able to store a 60 character string. Can you do a small test, hash a value and verify it without storing it to the database, then as a next step check your database field?